# Translate from monad to applicative

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

OK, so I know what the `Applicative` type class contains, and why that's useful. But I can't quite wrap my brain around how you'd use it in a non-trivial example.

Consider, for example, the following fairly simple Parsec parser:

```
integer :: Parser Integer
integer = do
  many1 space
  ds <- many1 digit
  return $ read ds
```

Now how the heck would you write that without using the `Monad` instance for `Parser`? Lots of people claim that this can be done and is a good idea, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
integer :: Parser Integer
integer = read <$> (many1 space *> many1 digit)
```

Or

```
integer = const read <$> many1 space <*> many1 digit
```

Whether you think either of these are more readable is up to you.

Comment: We want to ignore the value (but not the effect) of `many1 space`, and apply `read` to the value of `many1 digit`. (Sorry, I've just got in, it's late, I'm tired: I'm playing fast and loose with the terminology.) If you imagine `s` and `d` represent the values of `many1 space` and `many1 digit` respectively, then the value (ignoring effects) of `const read <$> many1 space <*> many1 digit` is `const read s d` = `read d`.

Answer (score 39):

I'd write

```
integer :: Parser Integer
integer = read <$ many1 space <*> many1 digit
```

There's a bunch of left associative (like application) parser-building operators `<$>`, `<*>`, `<$`, `<*`. The thing in the far left should be the pure function which assembles the result value from the component values. The thing on the right of each operator should be a parser, collectively giving the components of the grammar left-to-right. Which operator to use depends on two choices, as follows.

```
  the thing to the right is    signal  / noise
  _________________________            
  the thing to the left is \           
                            +-------------------
                    pure /  |   <$>       <$
                  a parser  |   <*>       <*
```

So, having chosen `read :: String -> Integer` as the pure function which is going to deliver the semantics of the parser, we can classify the leading space as "noise" and the bunch of digits as "signal", hence

```
 read <$ many1 space <*> many1 digit
 (..)    (.........)     (.........)
 pure    noise parser     |
 (.................)      |
     parser              signal parser
 (.................................)
                    parser
```

You can combine multiple possibilities with

```
p1 <|> ... <|> pn
```

and express impossibility with

```
empty
```

It's seldom necessary to name components in parsers, and the resulting code looks more like a grammar with added semantics.

Comment: Wow, I knew about `<$`, but I only ever used it if the thing to the left of it was a constant and the right was a simple value... I never thought about what would happen if I put a function to the left :P Nice trick

Answer (score 8):

Your example can be progressively rewritten to a form which more clearly resembles an Applicative:

```
do
  many1 space
  ds <- many1 digit
  return $ read ds
```

1. definition of `do` notation:

   ```
   many1 space >> (many1 digit >>= \ds -> return $ read ds)
   ```
2. definition of `$`:

   ```
   many1 space >> (many1 digit >>= \ds -> return (read ds))
   ```
3. definition of `.`:

   ```
   many1 space >> (many1 digit >>= (return . read))
   ```
4. 3rd monad law (associativity):

   ```
   (many1 space >> many1 digit) >>= (return . read)
   ```
5. definition of `liftM` (in non-`do` notation):

   ```
   liftM read (many1 space >> many1 digit)
   ```

This is (or should be, if I haven't messed up :)) identical in behavior to your example.

Now, if you replace `liftM` with `fmap` with `<$>`, and `>>` with `*>`, you get the Applicative:

```
read <$> (many1 space *> many1 digit)
```

This is valid because `liftM`, `fmap`, and `<$>` are generally supposed to be synonyms, as are `>>` and `*>`.

This all works and we can do this because the original example didn't use the result of any parser to build a following parser.

Comment: Cool! Another way to write `read <$ many1 space <*> many1 digit`. :) The last sentence is very important. Does that mean that this style corresponds to context-free grammars, and more general grammars must be parsed with monadic style?

Comment: @WillNess I'm not an expert on this, but I do believe that's the case.