# More fun with applicative functors

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

[Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123552/translate-from-monad-to-applicative) I asked about translating monadic code to use only the applicative functor instance of Parsec. Unfortunately I got several replies which answered the question I literally asked, but didn't really give me much insight. So let me try this again...

Summarising my knowledge so far, an applicative functor is something which is somewhat more restricted than a monad. In the tradition of "less is more", restricting what the code can do increases the possibilities for crazy code manipulation. Regardless, a lot of people seem to believe that using applicative instead of monad is a superior solution where it's possible.

The `Applicative` class is defined in `Control.Applicative`, whose Haddock's listing helpfully separates the class methods and utility functions with a vast swathe of class instances between them, to make it hard to quickly see everything on screen at once. But the pertinent type signatures are

```
pure ::    x              -> f x
<*>  :: f (x -> y) -> f x -> f y
 *>  :: f  x       -> f y -> f y
<*   :: f  x       -> f y -> f x
<$>  ::   (x -> y) -> f x -> f y
<$   ::    x       -> f y -> f x
```

Makes perfect sense, right?

Well, `Functor` already gives us `fmap`, which is basically `<$>`. I.e., given a function from `x` to `y`, we can map an `f x` to an `f y`. `Applicative` adds two essentially new elements. One is `pure`, which has roughly the same type as `return` (and several other operators in various category theory classes). The other is `<*>`, which gives us the ability to take a container of functions and a container of inputs and produce a container of outputs.

Using the operators above, we can very neatly do something such as

```
foo <$> abc <*> def <*> ghi
```

This allows us to take an N-ary function and source its arguments from N functors in a way which generalises easily to any N.

---

This much I already understand. There are two main things which I do *not* yet understand.

First, the functions `*>`, `<*` and `<$`. From their types, `<* = const`, `*> = flip const`, and `<$` could be something similar. Presumably this does *not* describe what these functions actually do though. (??!)

Second, when writing a Parsec parser, each parsable entity usually ends up looking something like this:

```
entity = do
  var1 <- parser1
  var2 <- parser2
  var3 <- parser3
  ...
  return $ foo var1 var2 var3...
```

Since an applicative functor does not allow us to bind intermediate results to variables in this way, I'm puzzled as to how to gather them up for the final stage. I haven't been able to wrap my mind around the idea fully enough in order to comprehend how to do this.

Comment: `<$>` and `<$` are not specific to `Applicative`. They can work on any `Functor`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `<*` and `*>` functions are very simple: they work the same way as `>>`. The `<*` would work the same way as `<<` except `<<` does not exist. Basically, given `a *> b`, you first "do" `a`, then you "do" `b` and return the result of `b`. For `a <* b`, you still first "do" `a` then "do" `b`, but you return the result of `a`. (For appropriate meanings of "do", of course.)

The `<$` function is just `fmap const`. So `a <$ b` is equal to `fmap (const a) b`. You just throw away the result of an "action" and return a constant value instead. The `Control.Monad` function `void`, which has a type `Functor f => f a -> f ()` could be written as `() <$`.

These three functions are not fundamental to the definition of an applicative functor. (`<$`, in fact, works for any functor.) This, again, is just like `>>` for monads. I believe they're in the class to make it easier to optimize them for specific instances.

When you use applicative functors, you do not "extract" the value from the functor. In a monad, this is what `>>=` does, and what `foo <- ...` desugars to. Instead, you pass the wrapped values into a function directly using `<$>` and `<*>`. So you could rewrite your example as:

```
foo <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3 ...
```

If you want intermediate variables, you could just use a `let` statement:

```
let var1 = parser1
    var2 = parser2
    var3 = parser3 in
foo <$> var1 <*> var2 <*> var3
```

As you correctly surmised, `pure` is just another name for `return`. So, to make the shared structure more obvious, we can rewrite this as:

```
pure foo <*> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
```

I hope this clarifies things.

Now just a little note. People *do* recommend using applicative functor functions for parsing. However, you should only use them if they make more sense! For sufficiently complex things, the monad version (especially with do-notation) can actually be clearer. The reason people recommend this is that

```
foo <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
```

is both shorter and more readable than

```
do var1 <- parser1
   var2 <- parser2
   var3 <- parser3
   return $ foo var1 var2 var3
```

Essentially, the `f <$> a <*> b <*> c` is essentially like lifted function application. You can imagine the `<*>` being a replacement for a space (e.g. function application) in the same way that `fmap` is a replacement for function application. This should also give you an intuitive notion of why we use `<$>`--it's like a lifted version of `$`.

Comment: In fact, `(<$)` and `(<$>)` are defined in `Data.Functor` and only re-exported from the `Control.Applicative` module :)

Comment: The key insight, then, seems to be that rather than running parsers, binding their result to names, and then using those names at the end, we can simply do `foo <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3`. Together with the hints from yatima, I think this gives me all I need to know.

Answer (score 13):

I can make a few remarks here, hopefully helpful. This reflects my understanding which itself might be wrong.

`pure` is unusually named. Usually functions are named referring to what they produce, but in `pure x` it is `x` that is *pure*. `pure x` produces an applicative functor which "carries" the pure `x`. "Carries" of course is approximate. An example: `pure 1 :: ZipList Int` is a `ZipList`, carrying a pure `Int` value, `1`.

`<*>`, `*>`, and `<*` are **not functions, but methods** (this answers your first concern). `f` in their types is not general (like it would be, for functions) but specific, as specified by a specific instance. That's why they are **indeed not** just `$`, `flip const` and `const`. The specialized type `f` specifies *the semantics of combination*. In the usual applicative style programming, combination means application. But with functors, an additional dimension is present, represented by the "carrier" type `f`. In `f x`, there is a "contents", `x`, but there is also a "context", `f`.

The "applicative functors" style sought to enable the "applicative style" programming, with effects. Effects being represented by functors, carriers, providers of context; "applicative" referring to the normal applicative style of functional application. **Writing just `f x` to denote application** was once *a revolutionary idea*. There was no need for additional syntax anymore, no `(funcall f x)`, no `CALL` statements, none of this extra stuff - *combination* was *application*... Not so, with effects, *seemingly* - there was again that need for the *special* syntax, when programming with effects. The slain beast reappeared again.

So came the [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) to again make the combination mean just application - in the special (perhaps effectful) *context*, if they were indeed *in* such context. So for `a :: f (t -> r)` and `b :: f t`, the *(almost plain)* combination `a <*> b` is **an application of carried contents** (or types `t -> r` and `t`), **in a given context** (of type `f`).

The main distinction from monads is, **monads are non-linear**. In

```
do {  x        <-  a
   ;     y     <-  b x
   ;        z  <-  c x y
   ;               return 
     (x, y, z) }
```

the computation `b x` depends on `x`, and `c x y` depends on both `x` and `y`. The functions are *nested*:

```
a >>= (\x ->  b x  >>= (\y ->  c x y  >>= (\z ->  .... )))
```

If `b` and `c` do *not* depend on the previous results (`x`, `y`), this can be made *flat* by making the computation stages return **repackaged, compound data** (this addresses your second concern):

```
a  >>= (\x       ->  b  >>= (\y-> return (x,y)))       -- `b  ` sic
   >>= (\(x,y)   ->  c  >>= (\z-> return (x,y,z)))     -- `c  `
   >>= (\(x,y,z) ->  ..... )
```

and this is essentially an applicative style (`b`, `c` are fully known in advance, independent of the value `x` produced by `a`, etc.). So when your combinations create data that encompass all the information they need for further combinations, *and there's no need for "outer variables"* (i.e. all computations are already fully known, independent of any values produced by any of the previous stages), you can use this style of combination.

But if your monadic chain has **branches** dependent on values of such "outer" variables (i.e. results of previous stages of monadic computation), then you can't make a linear chain out of it. It is *essentially* monadic then.

---

As an illustration, the first example from that paper shows how the "monadic" function

```
sequence :: [IO a] → IO [a]
sequence [ ] = return [ ]
sequence (c : cs) = do
  {  x       <-  c
  ;      xs  <-  sequence cs  -- `sequence cs` fully known, independent of `x`
  ;              return 
    (x : xs) }
```

can actually be coded in this "flat, linear" style as

```
sequence :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequence []       = pure []
sequence (c : cs) = pure (:) <*> c <*> sequence cs
                  --     (:)     x     xs
```

There's no use here for the monad's ability to branch on previous results.

---

a note on the excellent [Petr Pudlák's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211856/849891): in my "terminology" here, his `pair` is *combination* without *application*. It shows that the essence of what the Applictive Functors add to plain Functors, is the ability to combine. Application is then achieved by the good old `fmap`. This suggests *combinatory functors* as perhaps a better name (*update:* in fact, "Monoidal Functors" is the name).

Comment: `pure x` produces an action that has no side effects and returns `x`, i.e. the result is a "pure action".

Comment: @melpomene the action is not pure, it is effectful.

Comment: Then what are its effects?

Comment: @melpomene whatever is meant by `f` in `Applicative f => f a`. E.g. if `f` is `ZipList`, then its effect is the possibility of zipping.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. The effects aren't in the type; they're in (some of) the values, and not all values have effects. The Monad/Applicative laws ensure this (e.g. `return a >>= k  ==  k a` or `pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)`).

Comment: @melpomene `pure (1+) == (1+) <$ pure ()`. `pure (1+)` is not pure; `(1+)` is the same pure value in the two expressions, injected into some context. In the 2nd, with `fmap.const`. In the first, with `pure`.

Comment: @melpomene I've just came across [this related answer by Conor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5847800/849891). I think I'm in no contradiction with it.

Answer (score 8):

You can view functors, applicatives and monads like this: They all carry a kind of "effect" and a "value".  (Note that the terms "effect" and "value" are only approximations - there doesn't actually need to be any side effects or values - like in `Identity` or `Const`.)

- With `Functor` you can modify possible values inside using `fmap`, but you cannot do anything with effects inside.
- With `Applicative`, you can create a value without any effect with `pure`, and you can sequence effects and combine their values inside. But the effects and values are separate: When sequencing effects, an effect cannot depend on the value of a previous one. This is reflected in `<*`, `<*>` and `*>`: They sequence effects and combine their values, but you cannot examine the values inside in any way.

  You could define `Applicative` using this alternative set of functions:

  ```
  fmap     :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
  pureUnit :: f ()
  pair     :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
  -- or even with a more suggestive type  (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
  ```

  (where `pureUnit` doesn't carry any effect)
  and define `pure` and `<*>` from them (and vice versa). Here `pair` sequences two effects and remembers the values of both of them. This definition expresses the fact that `Applicative` is a *monoidal functor*.

  Now consider an arbitrary (finite) expression consisting of `pair`, `fmap`, `pureUnit` and some primitive applicative values. We have several rules we can use:

  ```
  fmap f . fmap g           ==>     fmap (f . g)
  pair (fmap f x) y         ==>     fmap (\(a,b) -> (f a, b)) (pair x y)
  pair x (fmap f y)         ==>     -- similar
  pair pureUnit y           ==>     fmap (\b -> ((), b)) y
  pair x pureUnit           ==>     -- similar
  pair (pair x y) z         ==>     pair x (pair y z)
  ```

  Using these rules, we can reorder `pair`s, push `fmap`s outwards and eliminate `pureUnit`s, so eventually such expression can be converted into

  ```
  fmap pureFunction (x1 `pair` x2 `pair` ... `pair` xn)
  ```

  or

  ```
  fmap pureFunction pureUnit
  ```

  So indeed, we can first collect all effects together using `pair` and then modify the resulting value inside using a pure function.
- With `Monad`, an effect can depend on the value of a previous monadic value. This makes them so powerful.

Comment: I still think you *take* pure values with `pure` and create the effectful things "carrying" them. `pure 1 :: ZipList Int` is not a pure value; it's a `ZipList` made out of pure `1`. I think. Similarly, in your `fmap pureFunction pureUnit` the function is pure, but `pureUnit` is not.

Comment: correction to the above comment: in your `fmap pureFunction pureUnit` which is equivalent to `pure pureFunction <*> pureUnit` it is `pureFunction` that is a pure value; `pure pureFunction` is not.

Comment: @WillNess You're right, I've chosen somewhat bad name. The `pureUnit` isn't really pure, it's an applicative value without an effect.

Comment: it can even [have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106628/terms-of-io-inside-haskell/71114711?noredirect=1#comment125716827_71114711), I think. if that effect is idempotent, the presence of `pure _` in a chain of actions changes nothing.

Answer (score 6):

The answers already given are excellent, but there's one small(ish) point I'd like to spell out explicitly, and it has to do with `<*`, `<$` and `*>`.

One of the examples was

```
do var1 <- parser1
   var2 <- parser2
   var3 <- parser3
   return $ foo var1 var2 var3
```

which can also be written as `foo <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3`.

Suppose that the value of `var2` is irrelevant for `foo` - e.g. it's just some separating whitespace. Then it also doesn't make sense to have `foo` accept this whitespace only to ignore it. In this case `foo` should have two parameters, not three. Using `do`-notation, you can write this as:

```
do var1 <- parser1
   parser2
   var3 <- parser3
   return $ foo var1 var3
```

If you wanted to write this using only `<$>` and `<*>` it should be something like one of these equivalent expressions:

```
(\x _ z -> foo x z) <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
(\x _ -> foo x) <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
(\x -> const (foo x)) <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
(const  . foo) <$> parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3
```

But that's kind of tricky to get right with more arguments!

However, you can also write `foo <$> parser1 <* parser2 <*> parser3`. You could call `foo` the semantic function which is fed the result of `parser1` and `parser3` while ignoring the result of `parser2` in between. The absence of `>` is meant to be indicative of the ignoring.

If you wanted to ignore the result of `parser1` but use the other two results, you can similarly write `foo <$ parser1 <*> parser2 <*> parser3`, using `<$` instead of `<$>`.

I've never found much use for `*>`, I would normally write `id <$ p1 <*> p2` for the parser that ignores the result of `p1` and just parses with `p2`; you could write this as `p1 *> p2` but that increases the cognitive load for readers of the code.

I've learnt this way of thinking just for parsers, but it has later been generalised to `Applicative`s; but I think this notation comes from [the uuparsing library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/uu-parsinglib/2.0.0/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-UU-Parsing.html); at least I used it at Utrecht 10+ years ago.

Comment: Cool! cf. [a recent answer by one pigworker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15124278/849891), in case you've missed it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add/reword a couple things to the very helpful existing answers:

Applicatives are "static".  In `pure f <*> a <*> b`, `b` does not depend on `a`, and so can be [analyzed statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7863380).  This is what I was trying to show in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123552/translate-from-monad-to-applicative/15159650#15159650) (but I guess I failed -- sorry) -- that since there was actually no sequential dependence of parsers, there was no need for monads.

The key difference that monads bring to the table is `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a`, or, alternatively, `join :: Monad m => m (m a)`.  Note that whenever you have `x <- y` inside `do` notation, you're using `>>=`.  These say that monads allow you to use a value "inside" a monad to produce a new monad, "dynamically".  This cannot be done with an Applicative.  Examples:

```
-- parse two in a row of the same character
char             >>= \c1 ->
char             >>= \c2 ->
guard (c1 == c2) >>
return c1

-- parse a digit followed by a number of chars equal to that digit
--   assuming: 1) `digit`s value is an Int,
--             2) there's a `manyN` combinator
-- examples:  "3abcdef"  -> Just {rest: "def", chars: "abc"}
--            "14abcdef" -> Nothing
digit        >>= \d -> 
manyN d char 
-- note how the value from the first parser is pumped into 
--   creating the second parser

-- creating 'half' of a cartesian product
[1 .. 10] >>= \x ->
[1 .. x]  >>= \y ->
return (x, y)
```

Lastly, Applicatives enable lifted function application as mentioned by @WillNess. 
To try to get an idea of what the "intermediate" results look like, you can look at the parallels between normal and lifted function application.  Assuming `add2 = (+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`:

```
-- normal function application
add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
add2 3 :: Int -> Int
(add2 3) 4 :: Int

-- lifted function application
pure add2 :: [] (Int -> Int -> Int)
pure add2 <*> pure 3 :: [] (Int -> Int)
pure add2 <*> pure 3 <*> pure 4 :: [] Int

-- more useful example
[(+1), (*2)]
[(+1), (*2)] <*> [1 .. 5]
[(+1), (*2)] <*> [1 .. 5] <*> [3 .. 8]
```

Unfortunately, you can't meaningfully print the result of `pure add2 <*> pure 3` for the same reason that you can't for `add2` ... frustrating.  You may also want to look at the [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Functor-Identity.html#Identity) and its typeclass instances to get a handle on Applicatives.

Comment: Yeah, this is the key difference between applicative and monad. Monad allows you to run arbitrary Turing-complete code to decide what the next parser [or whatever] should be, thus destroying any possibility of static analysis. Applicative, by being more restrictive, allows you to analyse and possibly optimise the whole parser. Like I said, "less is more". This is actually why I'm interested in applicative in the first place...