# `fail "zero"` as a way to generate Nothing in simple `a -> Maybe a` example

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm reading [a revealing example of using a bind operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_monad_examples):

```
Just 5 >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )
```

returns `Just 6`.

I'm confused by the behaviour of `fail` and its usefulness in the example. 
When looking at the code I thought `fail "zero"` may have a meaning:

- program never gets to that point
- laziness
- something else.

Then I realised that after a type cohesion, an exception becomes `Nothing` (documented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fail)). Still confusing for me that without type enforcement `fail` is just an error in program.

```
Prelude> fail "zero" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
Prelude> fail "abc" :: [Int]
[]
Prelude> fail "zero"
*** Exception: user error (zero)
```

My question is about usefulness of `fail "zero"` in this example.

Is it a proper reading `(\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )` attempts to be simple case for `a -> Maybe a` function?

What prevents us from using  `(\ x -> if (x == 0) then Nothing else Just (x + 1) )` if we just needed an illustration of `a -> Maybe a`?

I found this version below a much easier and shorter way to grasp same example.

```
Prelude> g x = if (x == 0) then Nothing else Just (x + 1)
Prelude> Just 0 >>= g
Nothing
Prelude> Just 1 >>= g
Just 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a proper reading `(\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )` attempts to be simple case for `a -> Maybe a` function?

Yes.

> What prevents us from using  `(\ x -> if (x == 0) then Nothing else Just (x + 1) )` if we just needed an illustration of `a -> Maybe a`?

Nothing.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Daniel's entirely correct answer, `fail` is a function from the [`MonadFail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html) typeclass. It was originally in the `Monad` typeclass, but it didn't really belong there, as some `Monad`s don't have a conception of failure. For those that do have a conception of failure, `fail` has the type `MonadFail m => String -> m a`. That is, for any type that implements the `MonadFail` interface, and any type `a`, `fail` can take a string and produce an instance of that type paramaterized by `a`.

For `Maybe a`, `fail s = Nothing`.

For `[a]`, `fail s = []`.

For `IO a`, `fail` raises an exception containing the string.

Many people write instances of `MonadFail` for types like `Either String a`, where `fail s = Left s`. The main reason this is not part of the standard library is because `Either` is a fairly abstract type, and although it's common to treat `Right` as success and `Left` as failure, it can be reasonably used as a `Monad` with the semantics flipped. (For instance, if you want to try N things, and move on to the next thing if one thing fails, but take the first result, then you need to use `Left` as the success case.)

Edit:

Also, when you write some code like

```
do 
  Just y <- getMaybe x
  return y
```

That gets desugared to:

```
do
  case getMaybe x of
    Just y -> return y
    _      -> fail "Failed pattern match"
```

This means that a failed pattern match will throw an exception in `IO a`, but be an empty list in `[a]`, and be a `Nothing` in a `Maybe a`.

Comment: Thank you for addition! The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fail) say `fail` _is invoked on pattern-match failure in a do expression._ Is this useful for anything else? Another way of keeping track of failed computations, like `Either`?

Comment: Edited post to include details of what "invoked on pattern match failure" means. It's mostly a way of making "failed computations" generic over different kinds of `Monad`s. One of my favorite uses of this is that you can write a lot of code that is generic over MonadFail, and then choose what type of error you want just by changing the types and some basic definitions.

Comment: Thank you for example @Izaak Weiss and the `MonadFail` workflow comment!