# Monadic sequence in terms of applicative functors

Tags: haskell

Let's say we have a monadic sequence:

```
doSomething = do 
    a <- f 
    b <- g 
    c <- h 
    pure (a, b, c)
```

We can easily rewrite it using applicative functor:

```
doSomething2 = (,,) <$> f <*> g <*> h
```

But what if the monadic sequence looks like this:

```
doSomething' n = do 
    a <- f n 
    b <- g a 
    c <- h b 
    pure (a, b, c)
```

Is it still possible to use applicative there? If not, what is the hindrance?
(Also it is written in a book that, despite this, we can use applicative and `join` together, but I don't see how to).

Comment: Short answer: no this can't be done with Applicative alone, in order to decide which "action" to perform next based on the result of a previous one, you need Monad.

Comment: this can't be done with Applicative alone *in general*, but for a *concrete* Applicative sometimes a nominally `a -> f b` function can be re-implemented so that it still is not essentially monadic, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647091/849891) in `bar = do { x <- [10, 100] ; r <- foo x ; return r } where foo :: a -> [a]; foo x = [x*2, x+3]` the function `foo`seemingly has a monadic bind-requiring type, but still `bar` can be coded with Applicative code only. ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211184/849891))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is precisely the extra power that Monad brings compared to Applicative. A monadic, or applicative, value of type `f a` can be thought of as being two parts: the "effects" (stuff happening in the `f` data structure), and the "value" (stuff happening in the values of type `a`). With Applicative, it is impossible for the effects to depend on the value, because the functions in Applicative give you no way to weave a function's results (the value) back into the effect. The `(>>=)` function in Monad gives you this power; `join` is equivalently powerful.

The key is that the signature for `(>>=)` contains a function that looks like `(a -> m b)`: you get to look at a pure *value* (`a`), and choose an effect `(m b)` based on that. Compare

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

to

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The last two accept only functions that operate entirely in the value realm: `(a -> b)`, and so cannot determine structure/effect based on values.

Of course you can still desugar this `do` notation, but you will have to use monadic operations in the result:

```
doSomething'' n =
  f n >>= (\a -> 
    g a >>= (\b -> 
      h b >>= (\c -> 
        pure (a, b, c))))
```